# Package apache2 has no installation candidate (Kali Linux)

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux

I've been trying for the past few days to install Apache2 on Kali Linux. No matter what I've tried, when I do

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

it says that there's no installation candidate for the package. I'm fairly new to Linux.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: "_Apache2 on Kali Linux_" ... why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your repo metadata? I am assuming your installation is new, so you probably need apt to look over your package sources and index the available packages. Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt install apache2`.

Answer (score 0):

Kali needs only one line in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` if necessary with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and save the file.

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Install [apache2](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/apache2): ← from kali-rolling repository

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
```